# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'DATABASE' when using scrapy shell

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapy-shell

I am trying to run the scrapy shell in the root of my project, but I keep getting an obscure error regarding some sort of DATABASE setting. I'm not sure if this is an SQLAlchemy thing...or some problem with my schema definition?

If I run `scrapy shell http://some_website.com` from any other directory outside of the project's path, I have no problem.

Trying to launch the shell:

```
me@me:~/my_spider$ scrapy shell http://some_website.com
2015-12-13 15:15:58-0800 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 0.24.4 started (bot: my_bot)
2015-12-13 15:15:58-0800 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11, boto, django
2015-12-13 15:15:58-0800 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'my_spider.spiders', 'DEPTH_LIMIT': 2, 'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN': 1, 'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': 1, 'SPIDER_MODULES': [''my_spider.spiders'], 'BOT_NAME': 'my_bot', 'COOKIES_ENABLED': False, 'LOGSTATS_INTERVAL': 0, 'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 5}
2015-12-13 15:15:58-0800 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions: TelnetConsole, CloseSpider, WebService, CoreStats, SpiderState
2015-12-13 15:15:59-0800 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, RandomUserAgentMiddleware, ProxyMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, MetaRefreshMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2015-12-13 15:15:59-0800 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
```

and here's the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/scrapy", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(execute())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 143, in execute
    _run_print_help(parser, _run_command, cmd, args, opts)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 89, in _run_print_help
    func(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 150, in _run_command
    cmd.run(args, opts)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/commands/shell.py", line 46, in run
    self.crawler_process.start_crawling()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 124, in start_crawling
    return self._start_crawler() is not None
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 139, in _start_crawler
    crawler.configure()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 47, in configure
    self.engine = ExecutionEngine(self, self._spider_closed)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/core/engine.py", line 65, in __init__
    self.scraper = Scraper(crawler)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/core/scraper.py", line 66, in __init__
    self.itemproc = itemproc_cls.from_crawler(crawler)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/middleware.py", line 50, in from_crawler
    return cls.from_settings(crawler.settings, crawler)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/middleware.py", line 35, in from_settings
    mw = mwcls()
  File "~/my_spider/pipelines.py", line 14, in __init__
    engine = db_connect()
  File "~/my_spider/libs/database/__init__.py", line 14, in db_connect
    url = URL(**settings.DATABASE)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'DATABASE'
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from what @tristan has pointed out and, according to a traceback - when you start the shell, Scrapy picks up your project settings that includes the pipelines, one of which is performing the `db_connect()` function, that uses the `settings.DATABASE` setting:

```
url = URL(**settings.DATABASE)
```

Make sure you have the `DATABASE` dictionary defined in your project settings.

Comment: This was indeed my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have a `settings` variable definition that scrapy is finding instead of the one it thinks it will find (or needs).

Instead of finding the `settings` object that the `scrapy/middleware.py` module `from_settings()` call is using, it's finding your settings object and looking to it to provide a `.DATABASE` attribute.  Without seeing the code you have in `my_bot`, the TraceBack and the lines of code from the most recent Python 2.7 scrapy:

```
 26     @classmethod
 27     def from_settings(cls, settings, crawler=None):
 28         mwlist = cls._get_mwlist_from_settings(settings)
 29         middlewares = []
 30         for clspath in mwlist:
 31             try:
 32                 mwcls = load_object(clspath)
 33                 if crawler and hasattr(mwcls, 'from_crawler'):
 34                     mw = mwcls.from_crawler(crawler)
 35                 elif hasattr(mwcls, 'from_settings'):
 36                     mw = mwcls.from_settings(settings)
```

suggest either a method resolution to a settings object that you didn't intend, or you followed a tutorial that had you supply `from_settings()` without implementing the required attributes.